# Special case of subset sum in $O(n)$

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

A sorted array $A[1..n]$ is given. Each element of $A[i]\in \mathbb{N}$, and for each $A[i],A[j]$ we have $A[i]+A[j]\leq n$. Find two elements $A[i], A[j]$ such that $(A[i]-i)+(A[j]-j)=0$. Give a deterministic $O(n)$ time algorithm for this problem.

I tackle with this problem as follow :

Calculate each $A[i]-i$ , and insert it into hash table $T$ that take $O(n)$ , then one time traverse $A$ such that to find and element that $A[i]-i=T[i]$. Each search take $O(1)$ in expected, but we must give a deterministic in $O(n)$.

Answer (score 2):

The assumptions $A[i] \in \mathbb N$ and $A[i] + A[j] \leq n$ together imply that $0 \leq A[i] \leq n$, and so $-n \leq A[i]-i \leq n$. This suggests maintaining an array $B[-n],\ldots,B[n]$, initialized with zeroes. We go over the elements of $A$ one by one. We put $B[A[i]-i] = i$, and then check whether $B[i-A[i]]$ is non-zero, say equal to $j$. If so, then $i-A[i] = A[j] - j$, and so $A[i] - i + A[j] - j = 0$. (This allows $i = j$; if you want to disallow it, reverse the order of these two steps.)

Comment: You might be interested in my answer, where I extended this idea to be constant auxiliary space as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in $O(n)$ time and $O(1)$ auxiliary space assuming
a model where the integers are stored as $w$-bit integers where
$w > 2$, and we can modify the input array (non-destructively).

---

First, we're going to steal two bits of storage space per element
from our array.

In one linear scan find the index $l$ such that the most
significant bit of $A[l-1]$ is 0 and the MSB of $A[l]$ is 1. This position
is unique because the array is sorted. Save
$l$ and clear all the top bits. Note that you can still retrieve
the original values, by computing $A[i] + 2^{(w-1)[i \geq l]}$.

Now apply the same process for both subarrays $A[1..l-1]$ and
$A[l..n]$, but this time stealing the *second* most significant
bit. The end result is that the top two most significant bits of
each element are zero, but we store three indices (where the top
two bits transition from $00$ to $01$, $01$ to $10$, and $10$ to
$11$) that allows us to recover the original data, when ignoring
the top two bits.

---

From this point on I assume that $A[i]$ refers to the original
values, but also that we have 2 bits of storage for each element,
using the above technique, which I'll call $P[i]$ and $N[i]$. We initialized
$P[i] = N[i] = 0$.

As Yuval Filmus notes because we have $A[i] \in \mathbb{N}$ and
$A[i] + A[j] \leq n$ we can assume $0 \leq A[i] \leq n$ and thus
$-n \leq A[i] - i \leq n$.

Initialize $z = 0$. Loop over $1 \leq i \leq n$ and compute $x = A[i] - i$:

1. If $x = 0$, if $z > 0$ return $(z, i)$. Otherwise store the index $z = i$.
2. If $x > 0$, check if $N[x] = 1$, if yes do a linear scan to
   find the earlier value $A[j] = -x$ (it must exist) and return
   $(j, i)$, otherwise set $P[x] = 1$.
3. If $x < 0$, check if $P[-x] = 1$, if yes do a linear scan to
   find the earlier value $A[j] = -x$ (it must exist) and return
   $(j, i)$, otherwise set $N[-x] = 1$.

If we reach $i = n$ and we didn't return a value, no solution
exists.

---

If necessary we can restore the input array to the original
state after finding the value above.

Comment: Are you assuming that the array is sorted?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, it's the first statement in the question.

Comment: Ah - missed that! Probably a two-pointer algorithm also works.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I tried thinking of one but was unsuccessful, because $A[i] - i$ is not monotonic even if $A[i]$ is. But maybe an even cleverer simple technique than mine exists, which is just brute-forcing two techniques together ^^